# Why are values I obtain from clock() unsynchronized with real time?

Tags: c, clock

I'm using the function `clock()` in C to get the seconds through ticks but with this little test program bellow I figured out that my processor hasn't being counting the ticks correctly, because the seconds are too much unsynchronized with real time and in addition I had to multiply the result by 100 to get something more similar to seconds but I think it doesnt make sense. In this program, 10s are almost equivalent of 7s in real life. Could someone help me to become the `clock()` function a bit more precise?

I'm using Beaglebone Black rev C with Kernel 3.8.13-bone70, Debian 4.6.3-14 and gcc version 4.6.3

thanks in advance!

Here's my test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(){

    while(1)
    printf("\n%f", (double)100*clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: does this mean that when you enter the date command at a command prompt that the displayed time is further and further off?

Comment: BTW:  %f is float, NOT double.   %lf is double

Comment: @user3629249: That's incorrect. `%f` is correct for both `float` and `double`, because `float` arguments are promoted to `double` (because `printf` is a variadic function). And the correct format for `long double` is `%Lf`, not `%lf`.

Comment: are you sure that 100,000 is the same as CLOCKS_PER_SECOND?

Comment: @user3629249: in `printf` it's both (actually, it's just `double`,  but `float`s are always implicitly converted to `double` when passed to variadic functions).

Comment: @user3629249, If you're stuck with a C89 library, `"%lf"` is undefined; in C99 and C11 libraries it is defined to be the same as `"%f"`.
And 100,000 isnt the same as CLOCKS_PER_SECOND although I had to multiply by 100 in addition to get something similar to seconds but I dont know why!

Comment: @user3629249, i'm checking the printed value by using my stopwatch

Comment: @KeithThompson,  irregardless of the parameters being promoted, the format specifier %f is for float arguments not double arguments (and the arguments are already double)

Comment: @user3629249: You are quite simply mistaken. `printf`'s `%f` format is for arguments of type `double`. `float` arguments are promoted to `double`, so `%f` works for them as well. Perhaps you're thinking of `scanf`, which has different rules (since it takes pointer arguments and they aren't promoted)? See [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 7.21.6.1, paragraphs 8 (for `%f`) and 7 (for the `L` length modifier). Or check any reference that covers the C `printf` function.

Answer (score 5):

The result returned by the `clock()` function isn't expected to be synchronized with real time. It returns

> the implementation’s best approximation to the processor time used by
>   the program since the beginning of an implementation-defined era
>   related only to the program invocation

If you want a high-precision indication of real (wall-clock) time, you'll need to use some system-specific function such as [`gettimeofday()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) or [`clock_gettime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) -- or, if your implementation supports it, the standard `timespec_get` function, added in C11.

Your program calls `printf` in a loop. I'd expect it to spend most of its time waiting for I/O, yielding to other processes, and for CPU time as indicated by `clock()` (when converted to seconds) to advance much more slowly that real time. I suspect your multiplication by 100 is throwing off your results; `clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC` should be a correct indication of CPU time.

Comment: I would, however, expect the CPU time used by such a tight infinite loop to be rather close to real time, so it is a curiosity that deserves further exploration ;-)

Comment: @SinanÜnür: The loop in the question includes a call to `printf`. I'd expect the process to spend most of its time waiting for I/O, yielding the CPU to other processes. I'd expect the value returned by `clock()`, when converted to seconds, to advance much more slowly than real time.

Comment: BTW, C11 now has the OS independent function `timespec_get`.

Answer (score 2):

Note [Keith Thompson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29905342/100754) which points you in the right direction.

However, one might expect a tight infinite loop to use most of the CPU in a given period (assuming nothing else is happening), and therefore any serious deviation between the CPU time spent on this tight infinite loop versus real time might be interesting to explore. To that end, I rigged this short program up:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    time_t t0 = time(NULL);
    while(1) {
        printf("%f\r", ((double) clock())/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        fflush(stdout);
        if (difftime(time(NULL), t0) > 5.0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

On Windows, I get:

```
C:\...\Temp> timethis clk.exe

TimeThis :  Command Line :  clk.exe
TimeThis :    Start Time :  Mon Apr 27 17:00:34 2015

5.093000
TimeThis :  Command Line :  clk.exe
TimeThis :    Start Time :  Mon Apr 27 17:00:34 2015
TimeThis :      End Time :  Mon Apr 27 17:00:40 2015
TimeThis :  Elapsed Time :  00:00:05.172
```

On *nix, you can use the `time` CLI utility to measure time.

The timing seems close enough to me.

Note also [Zan's point about comms lags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29905778/100754).

Answer (score 1):

Keith's answer is most correct but there is another problem with your program even if you did change it to use real time.

You have it creating output in a tight loop with no sleeps at all. If your output device is even a little bit slow the time displayed will be off by however slow the buffering is.

If you ran this over a 9,600 baud serial console for example, it could be as much as 30 seconds behind. At least, that's about how much lag I remember having observed in the far past when we still used 9,600 baud consoles.